# Pandas variable using lagged values

Tags: pandas, iteration

I am trying to write Pandas code to calculate accounting depreciations. The math is very simple:

```
depreciation(t)=depr_rate * [cumsum(investments(t)) - cumsum(depreciation(t-1))]
```

For example (with a depreciation rate of 30%):

Year 1: Investments 100 and depreciations 30
Year 2: Investments 100 and depreciations 51
Year 3: Investments   0 and depreciations 35.7

I am looking for a way to do this in Pandas.

My fix so far to convert the column to a list and then iterate over the list as follows:

```
inv_cum=list(df_inv.investment_cumsum)
depr_list=[]
for num in range(len(inv_cum)):
    depr_list.append(depr_rate*(inv_cum[num]-sum(depr_list[:max(0,num)])))
df_inv['depreciations']=depr_list
```

The fix works fine but I would prefer to use Pandas functionality. All help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add input and expected output

Comment: Hi Dani. Have tried to include data but markdown not very helpful in formatting.